# Unable to execute a stored procedure. An error occurred while calling o91.prepareCall. [JDBC Driver]String index out of range: 33

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am using py4j to execute a stored procedure(Redshift). The JDBC connection is created in AWS glue. Below is the code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

source_jdbc_conf_flywheel = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf('Redshift_QA')

from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.Connection")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.DatabaseMetaData")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.DriverManager")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.SQLException")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.CallableStatement")

dummy_url=source_jdbc_conf_flywheel.get('url')+"/"+'fwdb'

conn = sc._gateway.jvm.DriverManager.getConnection(dummy_url, source_jdbc_conf_flywheel.get('user'), source_jdbc_conf_flywheel.get('password'))
cstmt= conn.prepareCall("{call fwdb.fw.sp_unload_brand_to_datalake(?,?)}")
cstmt.setString(1, "xyz")
cstmt.setString(2, "xyz")
cstmt.execute()
conn.close()
```

I keep getting string out of index range error. The SP takes two parameters and unload the results to s3. Please help

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this ?

Comment: I used prepareStatement to execute the stored procedure